# How to get Haskell Stack to dynamically link with C?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Suppose we have a project with the following structure

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Setup.hs
├── app
│   └── Main.hs
├── cbits
│   ├── include
│   │   └── libCbits.c
│   └── lib
│       └── libCbits.so
├── dummy.cabal
├── package.yaml
├── src
├── stack.yaml
└── stack.yaml.lock
```

The file `libCbits.c` needs to be compiled to a .so file every time it updates with which Main.hs be linked.

I've tried adding `extra-lib-dirs` and `extra-include-dirs` to `package.yml`, which did not work.

How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: This is somewhat uncommon setup. Are you sure statically compiling C bits won't work for you?

Comment: @arrowd Let me explain it: I am writing a JIT compiler that can use external functions from `libCbits` following [Implementing a JIT](https://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm). I've tried statically compiling C bits but it didn't work. I am not quite sure if I am doing it the right way though.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this has the following directory structure instead:

```
⋮
├── cbits
│   └── libCbits.c
├── dummy.cabal
⋮
```

There are two changes here:

1. Under normal circumstances, an `include` directory has `.h` files only. This is a C convention. If you really want another layer of directory, you could name it `cbits/src` or `cbits/lib` or similar instead.
2. It is extremely unusual to manually manage a `.so`.

Then one puts some stuff like this in the appropriate `cabal` file:

```
c-sources: cbits/libCbits.c
cc-options: -O3 (or whatever)
```

You may be in an extremely unusual situation, where this kind of setup does not work. If so, to get more targeted advice you will probably have to say what you are trying to do that makes this setup unsuitable.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! I am following [Implementing a JIT](https://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/) and in chapter 4 the author manually compiled a `.so` so that the JIT can call extern functions during runtime. I just want to automate the compilation using stack.

Comment: @pe200012 Huh. Could there be a typo in your link? My browser claims it can't resolve that domain to an IP.

Comment: Strange...they changed the domain. https://smunix.github.io/www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/index.html